# String name = authentication.getName(); Authentication is null when debugging?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I am trying to allow an authenticated user to upload an image to an AWS S3 Bucket. I am able to push to the S3 bucket okay, but when I try to save to the logged in user's profile DB, it does not save since I am unable to pull the logged in user's username as it is null when I tried debugging. I am using JWT to authenticate and Spring Security but am not sure what I am doing wrong. I even tried logging in through my React.js fronted (Successfully) but it still does not pull the user's username for some reason. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Upload Method:

```html
@PostMapping("/image_upload")
    public ResponseEntity<?> singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                              RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
                                              Model model, Authentication authentication,
                                              UserProfile userProfile) {

        //Check if POST is empty
        if (file.isEmpty()) {

            return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse( "Please select a file to upload"));
        }

        //Hard coded bucketName -> linked to AWS
        String bucketName = "bucket";

        //Add timestamp to name to prevent duplicate names
        String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + "_" + file.getOriginalFilename();

        //getting aws access
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, accessSecret);

        //Building S3Client connection
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.Region)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .withRegion(region).build();

        try {
            //PUSH TO BUCKET
            File fileObj = convertMultiPartFileToFile(file);
            s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, fileObj));
            fileObj.delete();

            //Show Successful Upload
            ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse(fileName +": YOOOOOO")); //Does not print either, even though upload goes to S3.
           // redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", fileName + ": SuccessFully Uploaded On AWS S3");

            //Logged in user's username
            String name = authentication.getName(); //null
           CustomUserDetails customUser = (CustomUserDetails) userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(name);
            Long userId = customUser.getId();
            //Find UserProfile by id
           userProfile = userProfRepo.findByuserId(userId);

            //Set resource name to

            userProfile.setProfile_img(fileName);

            //Save database changes
            userProfRepo.save(userProfile);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        model.addAttribute("userProfile", userProfile);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("File Upload Successful"));

    }
```

WebSecurityConfig.java:

```html
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import com.App.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt ;
import com.App.security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter;
import com.App.security.services.CustomUserDetailsService;
/**
 * Web security configuration
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity()
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        // securedEnabled = true,
        // jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;
    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/profile").permitAll().and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .permitAll();
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

login Method:

```html
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);

        CustomUserDetails userDetails = (CustomUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt,
                userDetails.getId(),
                userDetails.getUsername(),
                userDetails.getEmail(),
                roles));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things you can look

1. is the user passing the correct JWT token.
2. Get Authentication from `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`
3. make sure your `authenticationJwtTokenFilter` is setting the authentication object correctly.
4. You have set the `sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)` so all the requests that need to be authenticated needs to contain jwt token.

Also, your code is a mess.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will look into these points. Any tips you can give on what I can do to not make it so messy?

Comment: lets say start with following ,
Create a service AwsConfig and create following beans
1. AWSCredentials
2 AmazonS3 
and inject it where u want to use it, instead of createing these objects again and again

Try moving all the login in a service and use controller just for request handling